# Is there any way to share data from one device to another with NFC, I don't want to use NFC Card to share the data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nfc, ndef

I want to create a project to share details from my iPhone to POS device. For testing I have created demo projects for writing NFC tags and reading NFC tags. But unfortunately, when I tap two devices, session ended and I won't be able to receive any message on tag readers end. Is there any way to share data from iPhone to POS devices.

I tried writing NFC tag on one device and reading NFC tags on second device. Format unsupported on receivers end. Just need to share data using NFC on tapping.

Comment: No. iOS apps cannot access host card emulation capabilities, so you cannot send data to a POS terminal.

Comment: iOS only have API for NFC reading. Writing is only available to wallet. That's explaining why there is no Apple Pay analogs on iOS.